# Custom Webmin Module - How to Control Category Display

Tags: webmin, webmin-module-development

I need to create a simple custom webmin module, which will be one button click to run a perl script I've created.

I read about the webmin module development at: http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/ModuleDevelopment which gave me a general overview. But I didn't find it to be a clear on how to actually create an item in the menu/categories.

I've looked at my `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` file, which shows my root at `/usr/libexec/webmin`. I then copied one of the subfolders to a test subfolder and modified its `module.info` file to try to a copy of an existing module to display in `webmin`. Just copying the folder and editing the file did not get things to display in the menu, which makes me think the menu/category layout is controlled somewhere else. If I go to `Webmin -> Webmin Configuration -> Webmin Modules -> Delete` I can see the copy of the module I made by the new name.

If I do `Webmin -> Webmin Configuration -> Webmin Modules -> Clone` then I can clone an existing item and there is an option for `Assign to Category`, which allows the clone to show up in the menu. However the directory `/usr/libexec/webmin` folder doesn't give the clone a new name, it just uses the existing directory and adds a number to the end of the directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root   4096 Oct  9 08:21 backup-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     13 Oct  9 08:20 backup-config2 -> backup-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root     13 Oct  9 08:53 backup-config3 -> backup-config
```

The clones also don't show up under the Delete Tab... e.g. They don't seem to be real modules, more like aliases.

I've tried to google examples, tutorials, and how to do simple setups, but there doesn't seem to be anything that gives a simple example on creating a new module and linking it into the menu/category. I believe my first approach of copying the subfolder from `/usr/libexec/webmin` and then editing the `module.info` is close to what really needs to happen, but I don't see how to link it into the menu. I looked at `Webmin -> Webmin Configuration -> Reassign Modules` and this shows my subfolder copy assigned to the `Webmin` category but doesn't seem to be showing up, or I'm not looking in the correct location.

What am I doing wrong? Specifically, what do I need to update or do to see the copied module in the menu?

### Update

I've tried the tutorial shown at: http://www.ehow.com/how_12048470_create-custom-webmin-module.html

I followed the example and made the module's name `foobar`. After making the new module, I deleted my `/etc/webmin/module.infos.cache` and refreshed by web browser, to make sure cache wasn't an issue. The example shows we categorize the module under `Servers` but its not showing up in my list. Below is a screenshot showing no `foobar`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found my missing piece...

The examples work but were missing one key piece of information. You need to give your user permissions to view the module after you set them up. To do so, I did:

```
Webmin -> Webmin Users -> root -> Available Webmin modules
Check the new unchecked modules
Save
```

After I did this, they displayed properly under each category.

Comment: If this is the answer, please click the tick/check mark when you get a moment. Self-accepted answers are very welcome here!